# Ruby on Rails overriding values in the changes hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add a before_validation hook that will clean up extraneous white space.  As part of that I wanted to also set any blank string values back to nil.  The reason for this being to prevent users from entering empty spaces into a required field in an attempt to bypass it.

The below is how I have tried to do this.  The changes[x][1].strip! line works as I would expect and gives me back a blanks line.  What I found surprising though is that where I attempt to set changes[x][1] = nil, the value of changes[x][1] remains unchanged.  Stepping through some debugging tests I found that not only did that fail, but any attempt to set changes[x][1] to ANY value fails to actually update the array!

I would love to hear what I'm doing wrong here, and how I can fix it.  Thanks so much!

```
def strip_whitespace
  changes.keys.each do |x|
    if changes[x][1].respond_to?(:strip!)
      changes[x][1] = nil if changes[x][1].blank?
      changes[x][1].strip!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you iterate the hash like that? I suggest you use `changes.values.each` thus you will void using the indexing `[x]`, which I think might be causing a problem for you if somehow ruby is preventing you in changing a collection you are currently iterating on.

Comment: The above code works fine on any standard hash, this issue is specific to the Rails built in changes hash.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do all those checks, the `.blank?` method returns true when the object:

- Is `nil`
- Is an empty string
- Is a string with only white space characters.

The `:presence` validation uses the `blank?` method, so you can use that one to prevent empty string from being introduced in your model's attributes.

**Edit:**

I tried reproducing your context creating the `changes` hash and it worked just fine:

```
changes = {one: ['q', 'w', 'e'], two: ['a', '', 'd']}

changes.keys.each do |x|
  changes[x][1] = nil if changes[x][1].blank?
end
# => [:one, :two]

changes
# => {:one => ["q", "w", "e"], :two => ["a", nil, "d"]}
```

Comment: I don't agree with the last bit. I think `[]` and `[]=` are different methods and the second one should do actual updating.

Comment: I totally agree with you. But what if the `[]=` method is not defined for a particular object you're using? Take the example of `ActiveRecord::Base` and its `attributes` method. It returns a clone of the actual attributes, so you can't directly update them using something like `model.attributes[:name] = 'Another name'`

Comment: I could see it being some cloned object if it weren't for the fact that the in place ! operators succeed in updating the changes hash.  Also; even if it were a copy of the attributes I should still see the update on changes from the command line.  I have done a step through debug and I can set changes[x][1] = "Foo".  This does not raise an exception, but changes[x][1] remains the item it was prior to assignment.  If however I do a changes[x][1].strip! or changes[x][1].squeeze! changes[x][1] is updated.

Comment: You're right, that really proves `changes[x][1]` is returning a reference and not a clone. I'll remove that part from my answer.

Comment: And here; further down the rabbit hole we go.  I have also tried testing it in a similar fashion to what you show above.  It works fine on a generated hash.  This seems to be something very Rails specific.  The changes hash I'm referring to here is the build in Rails changes hash that gets created between page submits. When the page is submitted you will have a hash containing keys for only those elements on the page that were updated. Each key then points to a 2 element Array where element 0 is the original value and element 1 is the new value coming in. On the Rails changes hash, this fails.